# How to Strip Carriage returns from a String

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, strip, carriage-return

I'm trying to process a string so that it contains no carriage returns however I'm having some trouble. I am currently using:

Visual Studio 2010:

```
strText = strText.Replace(vbCr, "")
```

The carriage returns are not being removed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
strText = strText.Replace("\n\r", "");
```

or

```
strText = strText.Replace("\n", "");
```

or

```
strText = strText.Replace("\r", "");
```

or

```
strText  = strText.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

Comment: Another option could be using `Environment.NewLine` instead of a hard coded string.

Comment: That is true, that would be better.

Comment: Though, in Visual Basic `vbCrLf` is probably the correct constant to do that. Thus prompting the question.

Comment: Unfortunately Sachin's answer did not work for my project as it provided syntax errors. However Steven's comments pointed me in the right direction. How do I mark Steven's comment as the answer?